# Bidi bug in starred posts' datetimes

Tags: bug, chat, hebrew

In the list of stars on the right-hand side of the chat room, the fairly recent posts are listed as having been posted "- 2d ago" (=two days ago) or "- 15m ago" (=fifteen minutes ago).

In my browser (Firefox 14.0.1 for Ubuntu), at least, the initial "- 1" or "- 15", if it appears after a right-to-left quotation of a chat post, also appears right-to-left, thus showing up on the left side of the text of the chat post.

[image]

I can think of two ways to fix this:

- Add `lang='en' dir='ltr'` to the `<html>` tag. Then, the Unicode bidirectional algorithm should interpret the (directionally neutral) hyphen-space-numeral as left-to-right. (Because it's between a right-to-left and a left-to-right character, it follows the ambient direction.)
- Add a left-to-right mark (U+200E) immediately before the "- 1" (before the hyphen), forcing the hyphen-space-numeral to be between two left-to-right characters and thus left-to-right.

The latter seems a surer bet (viz, that it will work in more browsers) to me.

Comment: Almost positive I've seen this issue discussed somewhere here or on MSO

Comment: Also happens in FF 14.0.1 on Mac.

Comment: Yeah, we've seen that a few times, but that was when people were joking around with RTL switching unicode. This is actually the first *valid* use case that I know of. At least assuming that message is actually meaningful. I don't know Hebrew :)

Comment: @balpha, yeah, the message is fine. `:-)`

Comment: @balpha Interesting, I was considering posting this a couple months ago, but after I saw all the meta.SO posts, I assumed it was pointless...

Comment: More comments on this are at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10502087#10502087 et seq.

Comment: Very similar: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4248

Answer (score 1):

Using @msh210's suggested method, I have written a jQuery proof of concept that accomplishes this locally, until such time as the devs fix this.

I've added the code to my chat room userscript, [which is available here.](https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/raw/master/ChatMods.user.js)

For the technically minded:

```
function bidi(){
    reg = /[\p{InHebrew}\p{InArabic}]/;
    $.each($('[id^=summary_]'), function(i, star){
        reg.test($(star).html()) && $(star).html($(star).html().replace(/ - <a/, ' &lrm;- <a'));
    });
}
```

Comment: +1, but I think you can omit the `.test` and just do the replacement. Otoh, I don't know if that'd be a help or a hindrance.

Comment: @msh210 I didn't know if adding &lrm; to _every_ message was necessary or would cause problems. If it's harmless, than I guess the test is just superfluous.